# Jquery click event only works once with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Compiled through handlebars, I have a list of topics. You can click on the topic, and through an ajax call it will then create a popup with more information. You can close the pop up, but after the first time, nothing on the page is clickable (even buttons unrelated to this. I've searched my SO topics, but nothing has lead me to the answer. I have noticed that without the ajax call attached to the click event, it will work every time.

How do I left the click even happen every time it's clicked, and not just the first time? Thank you!!

```
<div id="listing-topics" class="wrapper_form_dark">
</div>


<script id="listingTopics" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="wrapper_individual_listing_topic wrapper_form_dark">
        <div class="wrapper_listing_topics form_section">
          <a href={{link}} class="listing-topics">{{title}}</a><svg><use xlink:href="#starEmpty"/></svg>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
</script>



  <script id="popUpTopic" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="popUpTopic">
    <div class="topicClose">
    </div>
    <div class="show_topic wrapper_individual_listing_topic wrapper_form_dark" id='show_topic'>
      <h2 class="topic_title listing-topics">{{title}}</h2>
      <img src='/assets/icons/heart.png' class={{heartClass}}>
      <h6 class="topic_body">{{body}}</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  </script>
```

js file:

```
 var lookUpTopic = function(url)    {
    console.log(url);
    var source = $("#popUpTopic").html();
    var compiled = Handlebars.compile(source);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(result)   {

            var id = result.id;
            var title = result.title;
            var body = result.body;
            var level = result.level
            console.log(level);
            var heartClass = "unfavorited_heart_icon"

            var favlink = '/exchanges/' + id + '/favorite'; 
            var exchangeInfo = {title: title, body: body, heartClass: heartClass};
            var template = compiled(exchangeInfo);

            $('.topic-wrapper').append(template);
        },
        error: function(err)    {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}

var ready = function () {

$(document).on('click', '.listing-topics', function(e)  {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this);

  lookUpTopic(this.href);

  });


$(document).on('click', '.topicClose', function(e)  {
   console.log("clicky click!");
    //based on other SO I have also tried remove(), but does not work
    // $('.topicClose').remove();
    // $('.show_topic').remove();
    $('.topicClose').css("display", "none");
    $('.show_topic').css("display", "none");
 })


    $.ajax({
            url: '/exchanges',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result)   {
                // console.log(result);
                console.log("exchanges loaded");


                //COMPILE HANDLEBARS TEMPLATE FOR POPUP
                var source = $("#popUpTopic").html();
                var compiled = Handlebars.compile(source);

                //COMPILE HANDLEBARS TEMPLATE FOR LISTING TOPICS
                var listingSource = $("#listingTopics").html();
                var compiledTopics = Handlebars.compile(listingSource);


                for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)  {
                    var title = result[i].title;
                    var level = result[i].level;
                    var id = result[i].id;
                    var favlink = '/exchanges/' + id + '/favorite'; 
                    var link = '/exchanges/' + id;
                    var exchangeInfo = {title: title, link: link};
                    var template = compiledTopics(exchangeInfo);
                    $('.topic-wrapper').append(template);

              };

            },
            error: function(err)    {

            }
        });



var source = $("#popUpTopic").html();
var compiled = Handlebars.compile(source);

//COMPILE HANDLEBARS TEMPLATE FOR LISTING TOPICS
var listingSource = $("#listingTopics").html();
var compiledTopics = Handlebars.compile(listingSource);



}

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on("page:load", ready);
```

Comment: Are you replacing the elements with your ajax call? or just adding additional content to the page and display a popup? try to describe what you ajax call is doing, cause maybe you are loosing the registered click handler because you replace the element that has click handler registered with a fresh one.

Comment: @MohammedElSayed onclick, addi content, and then hiding that content so you can click on another topic, and another popup will display.

Comment: At first I thought… event delegation! But then I see you are already using throughout.

Comment: @tmslnz that was a huge thing i saw too from the other SO, but I don't think it's that. I think it has to do with the ajax call

Comment: Had a look at your JS file: it is a bit of a mess. Can you tidy it up a bit? The Handlebars compiling at the bottom, before `ready`, that stuff shouldn't be there. If you run your file through a linter, lots of big and small issues will become obvious. Also without even a broken example it's kinda hard to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Ah, also: you have `on('click', '.listing-topics'…` but the only `listing-topics` I see in your markup is an `id=`, whereas your code is looking for a classname.

Comment: This pen is an attempt at cleaning up the JS you shared http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VmLePe

Comment: @tmslnz thanks for the codepen example, but it doesn't do anything. The link that triggers the event has a class called listing-topics.